# fetch emails with php lib that suports oauth 2

Tags: email, oauth, google-api, imap

I'm trying to get mail(imap) from google by oauth authorization . I have got the authorization to work, but I can not retrieve the emails. As I understand it should be posible. But Google does not have any api to retrieve mail(?). However, I found the following:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

That says:

> Accessing mail using IMAP and sending mail using SMTP is often done
>   using existing IMAP and SMTP libraries for convenience. As long as
>   these libraries support the Simple Authentication and Security Layer
>   (SASL), they should be compatible with the OAuth mechanism supported
>   by Gmail. In addition to using a library which supports IMAP and SMTP,
>   developers also will want to use one of the many existing libraries
>   for handling OAuth

Do anyone know a existing library that i can use and that has some documentation as well. Im using google-api-php-client.

The code

```
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(-1);
require_once '../../src/apiClient.php';




$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Mailendar');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
// Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=contacts to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
 $client->setClientId('secret');
 $client->setClientSecret('secret');
 $client->setRedirectUri('secret');
 $client->setDeveloperKey('secret');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  echo "token is set";
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {


  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $client->revokeToken();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

 MAGIC HAPPENS HERE!!!...but is unkown for me ofc

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if (isset($auth)) {
    print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
  } else {
    print "<a class=logout href='?logout'>Logout</a>";


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesnt allow you to retrieve mail with oauth 2.0 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can fetch mails using OAuth.

Implemented a simple library.
Delete mail function is not yet added. But you can take a look if it satisfies your need.

Try example. https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP